# Passing value from a form to another form (C# winforms)

Tags: c#

Please take a look at this image:
[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img21/6190/64635037.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img21/6190/64635037.png)

I have a `MDI` form with 2 different child forms in it (`Form1`, and `Form2`).
Is it possible to pass the value of `textBox1` in `Form1`, to `textBox1` in `Form2`? (Supposedly, when I press the button as a trigger).

If yes, how? Please help.. thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an excellent article about it: [Passing Values between Forms in .NET 1.x with C# and VB.NET examples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/passingvaluesbetweenforms.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If either form has reference for other form then it can be easily done via creating a public method. For example, in form2

```
  public void PassValue(string value) 
    {
      textBox1.Text = value;
    }
```

And in form1,

```
button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   form2Ref.PassValue(textBox1.Text);
}
```

So how to you get form2 ref in form1, that can be done via MDI Main form - you need to use two properties: MdiParent to go to your parent and its MdiChildren property to enumerate via all child forms.