# Input from main form to another form

Tags: c#

I want to receive an input to the 2nd form from the main form.
I've tried to generate a method in the 2nd form, that's what I got:

```
internal Form2 Method(string value)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The value from the 1st form should be passed into "value" variable.
How do I return "value" as a string, so I can use it?

By the way, I don't know how to work with "internal" access modifier.

Comment: Generated method means you are suppose to return `Form2 object` in this method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing value from a form to another form (C# winforms)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492622/passing-value-from-a-form-to-another-form-c-winforms)...among sooooo many other dupes.  A simple search anywhere would get you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one class like

```
Public Class ValueTransfer
 {
  public string Value1{get;set;}
  }
```

Now you can create a Object of ValueTenasfer from from1 like

```
ValueTransfer v=new ValueTransfer();
 v.Value1="string";
```

and pass the class object into Other from method

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create method just add one parameter constructor for second  form so that whenever you need to pass value in second form at that time just create a object of second form with parameter whatever you want to pass to it else just create object with without parameter.

```
Form1()
{
     String to_pass = "abcdefg";
     Form2 formsecond = New Form2(to_pass);         
}

Form2(string to_pass)
{
     MessageBox.Show(to_pass);
}
```

But Dont Forget to Add parameterised Constructor before use this otherwise you get error for that.